# ¿Como mantener el nombre del archivo al descargarlo?

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Tengo un pequeño problema con el nombre de los archivos cuando estos son descargados. Asi los descargo

```
public function expensesAndTravel(){

   $file = storage_path() . '\app\excel\REPORTE DE GASTOS Y VIATICOS.xlsx';
   $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

   return response()->file($file, $headers);

}
```

El archivo se descarga sin problema, pero el nombre del archivo lo toma de como tenga declara mi ruta, en este caso

```
Route::get('files/expenses-travel', array(
   'as'   => 'files.expenses.travel',
   'uses' => 'FilesController@expensesAndTravel'
));
```

Se descarga con el nombres de `expenses-travel`, en la documentacion de `laravel` no encuentro nada con respecto a mantener el nombre, sin embargo si se puede con el metodo `response->donwload()`, pero con el `file()` que es el que necesito no puedo, la unica alternativa que encontre es poner el nombre completo del archivo como el nombre de mi ruta. ¿Hay alguna forma de mantener el nombre desde mi controlador y que no tome el nombre de la ruta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera PHP tradicional es:

```
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$nombreDeArchivo);
```

En tu caso probaría con:

```
$headers = [
  'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename='. $nombreDeArchivo
];

return response()->file($file, $headers);
```